# Do we need the Drug tag, or can it be discarded?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-deletion

Do we need the [drug](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drug) tag? It has no wiki, and only 6 questions. "Drugs" are not a statistical topic. While it's true that there are statistical components to medical research about the benefits and detriments about drugs, these are parts of larger topics that are subsumed by other tags (statistical hypothesis tests, for instance).

Comment: Both biostats and medicine tags are replacements

Comment: The tag is now gone, so the consensus seems clear

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's [clinical-trials](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clinical-trials) that should overlap with "drug" while being more relevant. We have few other relevant tags as well. "Drug" seems broad and not really helpful.

Answer (score 9):

With 'drug' I might potentially think about pharmacology which is about dynamics and kinetics. But all of the 6 question seem to be just some clinical trial, where Tim mentions there's already a tag [clinical-trials](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clinical-trials) (currently 392 cases). It seems superfluous to place have an additional tag for just those cases of clinical trials that involve drugs.

[How to study the effect of 2 drugs (used singly and in combination) compared to a placebo on a disease](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236099/how-to-study-the-effect-of-2-drugs-used-singly-and-in-combination-compared-to)

[Most appropriate calculation of mean and standard deviation for drug compliance?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/501193/most-appropriate-calculation-of-mean-and-standard-deviation-for-drug-compliance)

[Study the effect of 2 drugs on a symptom caused by 2 diseases](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236480/study-the-effect-of-2-drugs-on-a-symptom-caused-by-2-diseases)

[Percentage change](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/416150/percentage-change)

[Test for synergy using Bliss independance model for two drugs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/609687/test-for-synergy-using-bliss-independance-model-for-two-drugs)

[How to calculate whether a disease outcome in a population is by chance or significant?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/370372/how-to-calculate-whether-a-disease-outcome-in-a-population-is-by-chance-or-signi)

The last one might be more of an epidemiological study rather than a clinical trial. It is difficult to say because the question is not very clear.

---

In addition there is a tag [medicine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine), which has 144 questions. That might also need to be added to clinical-trials, although not every case out of those 144 might be fitting such migration.

Comment: We could create a `[pharmacokinetics]` tag in the future, if we need it.